# Match data frame values to multiple vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which every column contains different measurements except the first column which contains IDs. I want to create a smaller data frame which contains all columns for only those IDs which are outliers in at least one column. Here's what the data frame looks like now:

```
        BRICK       MARBLE          MASONITE        STEEL
ff5     1.9870268   0.3344881       0.09917627      3.205099
fdd     1.8088945   0.5292931       0.10868434      1.835525
fd9     1.2062831   0.2696240       0.12047189      3.279331
```

I have created vectors containing the outliers in each column using:

```
outliers_Marble = boxplot(Material$MARBLE, plot=FALSE)$out
```

I figured out how to make mini data frames that match a single outliers vector using

```
newframe = Material[match(outliers_Marble, Material$MARBLE,]
```

The part that has me stumped is applying this method to each column with the appropriate outliers vector. I know I could do each one manually then combine the data frames using but I am really hoping that someone can help me find a way to combine multiple calls of the **match** function into a single command. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following...

```
#Defining function for outlier
outLierFun = function(x){boxplot(x, plot=FALSE)$out}

#Removing column for which outlier test not needed
colNames = setdiff(colnames(Material),'BRICK')

#Finding out outlier
outliers = lapply(Material[colNames ], FUN = outLierFun)

#Empty Dataframe
newFrame = Material[0,] 
for(i in colNames){
  temp = subset(Material, get(i) %in% outliers[[i]])
  newFrame = unique(rbind(newFrame, temp))
}
#Final results
newFrame
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked and it is full of interesting code that I will probably find very useful once I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some test data with outliers added

```
set.seed(14)
dd<-data.frame(
    ID=paste0("ff",1:50),
    BRICK=rnorm(50,2),
    MARBLE=runif(50),
    MASONITE=runif(50, 0, .4),
    STEEL=rnorm(50,5)
)
dd$BRICK[5]<-6
dd$MARBLE[13]<-1.7
dd$MASONITE[26]<- -2
dd$STEEL[30]<- 20
```

Rather than using `boxplot`, i went to `boxplot.stats` to get the edges of the wiskers to make it easier to find the index of outliers. Here's how you can do that

```
outliers<-unique(unlist(lapply(dd[-1], function(x) {
    ex <- boxplot.stats(x)$stats; which(x<ex[1] | x>ex[5])
})))
```

And we can see that we found them

```
> outliers
[1]  5 13 26 30
```

Now i've already combined and removed duplicates from outliers, now I can get them out of the table

```
newframe <- if(length(outliers)>0)
      dd[-outliers, ]
    else 
      dd
```

Comment: what about some form of `apply(dd,2, function(x) IQR(x) * 1.5 + median(x) ) type of thing?` the double `unlist` `lapply` makes me think "it can't be this hard". but it's late and I can't think right meow.

Comment: @anamnesis I'm not sure where you're going with that. I use the `lapply` because each column could have a different number of outliers and in this case it's really the same as `apply(,2,)` without the random constant that may mean rows or columns (I always forget which is which). There's only one `unlist`; there's a `unique` outside of that to make sure i don't double count anyone.